# RSpec - how to stub controller method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rspec

I have a controller which has some special authentication as it is really an API available to a specific remote system.

In RSpec (2.7), I want to bypass that authentication, but I can't seem to get it working.  From what I read, I should be doing something like this:

```
controller.stub!(:restrict_soa_access).and_return(true)
```

But if I do that, I just get:

```
spec/controllers/soa/user_controller_spec.rb:42: undefined method `stub!'
for #<RSpec::Core::Hooks::AfterHooks:0xb673a8dc> (NoMethodError)
```

In response to the comments, I have also tried using `Soa::UserController.stub!` which gives an identical error, and also `@controller.stub!`, when I get undefined method for nil:NilClass.

I'm not stubbing any other stuff.  Is there something I need to do to enable stubbing or is my stub code just wrong?

Comment: Are you using `controller.stub!` or are you using the actual controller's name e.g. `User.stub!`?

Comment: are you using @controller.stub!(:restrict_soa_access).and_return(true) ?

Comment: I was using exactly what I wrote.  I've tried both of the suggestions with just about the same results.  Will put more detail of the attempts in the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

i had a similar problem, solved it with following requires:

```
require 'rspec/mocks'
require 'rspec/mocks/spec_methods'
require 'rspec/mocks/standalone'
```

could you report back if that works for you?

Comment: That runs now - the stubbing for some reason doesn't have the desired effect (opening the class and redefining restrict_soa_access does work, but takes 5 lines instead of one).